# Mean Stack: set default path

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, npm, mean-stack

where i can set the default path for a Mean Stack Application?
Local path is

```
http://localhost:3000
```

but i'd like the application starts at

```
http://localhost:3000/myapp/
```

In my mind i would expect my routing won't change:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

When i deploy on my server i want to have my application running on port 80 and in its separated context, like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myapp/
```

the routing sounds like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myapp/home
http://www.myserver.com/myapp/login
```

and if i point on a not set route:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myapp/notexists
```

it redirects on its base:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myapp/
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

client side:
In the main view (is it's a single page application) in the head section we should set the base href path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/my-base-path">
    <title>My-pplication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
</head>
```

All my request will start with

```
http://mysite/my-base-path/...
```

Server side:

I'm using Express so, when starts the app.js (or whatever it is the name):

```
var express = require('express');
...
var app = express();
...
    // Define where are located the external apis
var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
var authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
var registerRoutes = require('./routes/register');
var userr = require('./routes/userProfile');
...
...
app.use('/my-base-path/', appRoutes);
app.use('/my-base-path/user',userRoutes)
app.use('/my-base-path/login', authRoutes);
app.use('/my-base-path/register', registerRoutes);
```

Hope this it can be useful.